# How to remove properties that don't have a setter from properygrid c#

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am making an app in Winforms where the user selects an object from a list (all of which are different classes) then edit its properties. Some of the objects have properties greyed out because they don't have a setter. Is there a way to automatically remove those properties from the grid, or get a list of all entries like that and remove them programmatically.

Thank you.

Comment: It's usually done using a custom Designer, overriding `PostFilterProperties` (and `PreFilterProperties`, if necessary). You receive the Control's Properties as a Dictionary. You can then decide if you want to remove the property from the collection, or simply use TypeDescriptor to set the `BrowsableAttribute` of some proeperties to `false` (e.g., `properties["Some Property"] = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(this.Component.GetType(), (PropertyDescriptor)properties["Some Property"], new BrowsableAttribute(false));`)

Comment: Thank you for responding. What is the class I should inherit from for the custom Designer?

Comment: A class derived from [`ControlDesigner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner) (directly or indirectly). So `ControlDesigner` itself (or any other existing custom class you have derived from it), or `ParentControlDesigner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Just use PropertyTab and filter out the properties when it collects them.